# how can i search a file find a string and get all the text between / /

Tags: c#

ok i trying my best to get this string

```
"/i/models/fc6d6067621442ebb6f4238636363d47/textures?optimized=1"
```

but i need to get the jumble of numbers and between the // only and save it to a string because each json file i open has a different amount of numbers

i tried using regex but it finds different concordances in the file and i only need the one that matches this line

the file is a json file

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuoEB.png

but not sure how to accomplish this

this is the code i tried

```
            List<string> found = new List<string>();
            string line;
            using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(Application.StartupPath + "\\textures.json"))
            {
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line.Contains("textures?optimized=1"))
                    {
                        texturemodel = line;
                    }
                }
            }
```

this code does work and does get the line needed only issue i have with it it has ;} on the end of it so its nearly working but not sure how to remove the white space at the start and the ;{ at the end of the file the white space is at the beginning of the file

thanks in advance elfenliedtopfan5

Comment: Have a look at string.Split().

Comment: Use `Trim` function to remove the white spaces at the start and at the end. Also, you can use `Endswith` function to identify if the string `;{` or `;}` exists in the line. If exists then use `Substring` function to get rid of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are sure that *that* would always be the format, try `string.Split()`

```
var stringWithJumbledNumbersAndLetters = "/i/models/fc6d6067621442ebb6f4238636363d47/textures?optimized=1";

var splitString = stringWithJumbledNumbersAndLetters.Split('/');
//splitString[0] = i;
//splitString[1] = models;
//splitString[2] = fc6d6067621442ebb6f4238636363d47;
//splitString[3] = textures?optimized=1;
return splitString[2];
```

or direct would be

```
var stringWithJumbledNumbersAndLetters = "/i/models/fc6d6067621442ebb6f4238636363d47/textures?optimized=1";

return stringWithJumbledNumbersAndLetters.Split('/')[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "/i/models/fc6d6067621442ebb6f4238636363d47/textures?optimized=1";
String[] result = s.split("/");
System.out.println(result[3]);
```